# How to overlay 2 page indicator over eachother in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

i want to create indicator that overlay each other but couldn't find a way to it
[image for design i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LKQ4.png)

i have used smooth_page_indicator package for it

and this is how it looks
[image how may code looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHZIm.png)

this is my code for animates smooth indicator

```
 AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
            activeIndex: activeIndex,
            count: 2,
            onDotClicked: (index) => controller.animateToPage(index),
            effect: WormEffect(
              dotHeight: 5,
              dotWidth: 33,
              spacing: 0,
              dotColor: Color.fromARGB(71, 7, 7, 7),
              activeDotColor: Color(0xff625D5D),
            ),
          )
```